# Python Библиотека discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

TOKEN = 'OTQxMDYzMTE0ODU2NzM0NzMw.GqPH5Y.mpPMUYhfeXq-hheeFZLigqsUM-zuk45mb6LSy8'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True) # разрешаем передавать аргументы
async def test(ctx, arg): # создаем асинхронную функцию бота
    await ctx.send(arg) # отправляем обратно аргумент

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Ошибка:

```
#Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miroa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\miroa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\miroa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\miroa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\miroa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: arg is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Посоветую вам удалять токен бота при показе кода бота третим лицам, иначе кто-то может его использовать в не самых лучших целей, а сейчас лучше перегенерировать токен бота

Answer (score -1):

Я не ввёл текст после команды(гений....

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).